# create array for morris js in laravel

Tags: arrays, json, laravel, morris.js

I have difficulty loading certain data from the table to get a json array and include it into the morris js donut (example: https://codepen.io/ncarlucci/pen/JYxQBK)

I want to load from the table `subscriber` the different names from the column `type` and count them to get the following array:

```
[
    {value: 50, label: 'typename1'},
    {value: 25, label: 'typename2'},
    {value: 25, label: 'typename3'},
],
```

if I do it like this:

```php
$subscriber = Subscribe::select('type')->get()->groupBy('type')
    ->map(function($subscribe){
        return $subscribe->count();
    })->toJson();
```

I get the follow output, but it is false:

```
{"company":1,"person":16,"user":6}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a nicer way to handle your case, but since you didn't provide more informations about your model or database structure, this should work:

```php
$subscriber = Subscribe::select('type')->get()
    ->groupBy('type')
    ->map(function($subscribe, $label) {
        return ['value' => $subscribe->count(), 'label' => $label];
    })
    ->values()
    ->toJson();
```

The key is to build the inner array element within the map function, then call `values()` to get rid of the unneded outer label left by the map function.

If you need further explaination, just ask in the comments below